# How to align horizontally (and vertically) the boxes using display table-cell?

Tags: html, css

How to align horizontally (and vertically) the boxes using display table-cell?

[image]

```
vertical-align: middle; 
display: table-cell;
```

I have this sample fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lrmg3zna/

Comment: Where do you want to align them to?Or with respect to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a slight change in your `DOM` you can align your block both `vertically` as well as `horizontally`.

```
<div style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background: blue; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 auto;display: table-cell; text-algin: center;">
<!-- insert a div here -->
     <div style="height: 200px; display: block; width: 200px; margin: 0px auto;">
        <div style="height: 200px; display: table-cell;width: 200px; background: red; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 auto; text-algin: center;">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: green; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
        </div>
<!-- div ends here -->
     </div>
```

Here I've updated your [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/Lrmg3zna/1) too.

Please do have a look, it will do the trick for you.

Comment: Great! Thanks for this @vivekkupadhyay!